# dont stop the animation in listview

Tags: android, listview, animationdrawable, getview

i'm working with AnimationDrawable for download progressBar 
i put the animation in getview an it's working fine. but when i'm scrolling the list the animation has been stoped. is there any method in AnimationDrawable to fix this. like setCancelable in Dialog.

please help me ... thanks

```
ImageView anim = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) anim.getDrawable();
animation.start();
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found the answer :

i have to use ViewHolder im my ArrayAdapter class.

thank you all.